# Mysql Procedures: SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, mariadb

I'm trying to add this procedure. Its giving me error 1064 (42000) SQL Syntax. But I'm not sure where.

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE disable_expired_users
 BEGIN
   DECLARE @disable_this INT;
   SET @disable_this = SELECT id FROM my_users WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), expire_date) <= 0;
   IF NOT @disable_this IS NULL THEN
     UPDATE my_users SET is_active = 0 WHERE id IN @disable_this;
   END IF;
END; //
```

Comment: The error should include character position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE disable_expired_users
BEGIN
    UPDATE my_users
        SET is_active = 0
        WHERE expire_date < NOW();
END; //
```

Even better -- don't store redundant data (`is_active=0` vs `expire_date<NOW()`) -- simply use `expire_date<NOW()` whenever you need to check for expired.

If you are burdened by Workbench's restriction against `UPDATE` without blah blah, do something like this:

```
...
BEGIN
    SET @su = @@sql_safe_updates;
    SET sql_safe_updates = OFF;
    ... UPDATEs, etc ...
    SET sql_safe_updates = @su;
END //
```

Comment: Well, if I run just the UPDATE part in my mysql workbench it'll say that I can't update without putting a WHERE with ID, and that I have to disable safe mode, and bla bla bla. If I create this in a procedure, will it run any way?

Comment: I don't think so.  I added 3 lines to solve it (in a Proc).

Comment: Man, I never through I'd get so many responses from my question. I glad everyone here is eager to help. Thanks. I'll try that. I'm guessing this would work on triggers as well, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @disable_this = SELECT id FROM my_users WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,  
NOW(), expire_date) <= 0;
```

I think the problem is here.

Try

```
SET @disable_this = (SELECT id FROM my_users WHERE  
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), expire_date) <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add parentheses:

```
SET @disable_this = (SELECT id FROM my_users WHERE  
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), expire_date) <= 0);
```